# How can you get more than the default information from Google Sign In?

Tags: javascript, api, google-plus, google-signin, google-plus-signin

Using  getBasicProfile(), google lets us get basic profile data. Name, profile picture, email. For example:

```
var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
console.log("ID: " + profile.getId());
console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());
```

But what about other profile information, such as perhaps age, location, or gender? Is it possible to get these, and if so, how? I know that since I have a Google+ account, I have the city where I live, and where I work. Am I able to ask our user to grant access to more information, for example, the way facebook lets you? Or are we restricted to just these basic details?

Comment: Have you looked into the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) ?